# Dynamic conditional chaining functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, ecmascript-6

I am building a search functionality with multiple search criteria.

Is there any way we could dynamically generate single line of chainable filters including custom methods.

**Data:**

| SN | EventDate | Activity | Devices | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/12/20 | Sports | Fitbit | Archived rewards via running |
| 2 | 13/12/20 | Sports | Apple | Achieved rewards via running |
| 3 | 14/12/20 | Purchase | NA | Purchased coins for purchase |
| 4 | 14/12/20 | Sports | Fitbit | Archived rewards via running |
| 5 | 16/12/20 | Sports | Fitbit | Archived rewards via running |

from below filter condition I am expecting

| SN | EventDate | Activity | Devices | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/12/20 | Sports | Fitbit | Archived rewards via running |
| 2 | 13/12/20 | Sports | Apple | Achieved rewards via running |
| 4 | 14/12/20 | Sports | Fitbit | Archived rewards via running |

**Input Filter Condition:**

```
const input = [
  {
    Field: 'Activity',
    Operation: 'EQUALS',
    Values: 'Sports'
  },
  {
    Field: 'EventDate',
    Operation: 'DATEBETWEEN',
    Values: {startDate:2020-12-12, endDate: 2020-12-15}
  },
  {
    Field: 'Devices',
    Operation: 'INCLUDES'
    Values: {Fitbit,Apple}
  },
  {
    Field: 'All', // if ALL then all fields else array of fields
    Operation: 'GLOBAL',
    Values: 'Run'//keyword to search
  }
];
```

Something like below

```
global(objects, keyword) {
    retturn objects.filter(object => Object.values(object).some(i => i.includes(keyword)));
}

const filteredList = FilterModule
                    .include(field, array)
                    .equals(field, value)
                    .equals(field, value)
                    .global(field, array);
```

Need to generate dynamic filter modules based on input filter condition all the condition's are 'AND' condition.

only via JavaScript

Comment: https://github.com/mihaifm/linq

Comment: Why is `Values` a string or invalid syntax?

Comment: You want to generate JavaScript code? I don't really get the question here... Please also fix the syntax errors you have in your code.

Comment: Yes, but the sample is not clear because of the syntax errors. It is not clear whether `Values` is supposed to be equal to strings with some non-valid JS code... It is not easy to see what you are doing there. Cannot be hard for you to fix the syntax errors, and remove ambiguity...

Comment: No reaction? Also, the first argument to `global`... it is "All", and in the implementation you have `objects` as parameter. Not sure how that can match... Care to clarify all this?

Comment: @trincot kindly open this question to others, this feature will be much helpful to the world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create functions with a closure over the key/value and expect the object for checking.

`DATEBETWEEN` expects dates in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```js
const
    data = [{ SN: 1, EventDate: '2020-12-12', Activity: 'Sports', Devices: 'Fitbit', Description: 'Archived rewards via running' }, { SN: 2, EventDate: '2020-12-13', Activity: 'Sports', Devices: 'Apple', Description: 'Achieved rewards via running' }, { SN: 3, EventDate: '2020-12-14', Activity: 'Purchase', Devices: 'NA', Description: 'Purchased coins for purchase' }, { SN: 4, EventDate: '2020-12-14', Activity: 'Sports', Devices: 'Fitbit', Description: 'Archived rewards via running' }, { SN: 5, EventDate: '2020-12-16', Activity: 'Sports', Devices: 'Fitbit', Description: 'Archived rewards via running' }],
    input = [
        { Field: 'Activity', Operation: 'EQUALS', Values: 'Sports' },
        { Field: 'EventDate', Operation: 'DATEBETWEEN', Values: { startDate: '2020-12-12', endDate: '2020-12-15' } },
        { Field: 'Devices', Operation: 'INCLUDES', Values: ['Fitbit', 'Apple'] },
        { Field: 'All', Operation: 'GLOBAL', Values: 'Run' }
    ],
    operators = {
        EQUALS(k, v) { return o => o[k] === v; },
        DATEBETWEEN(k, v) { return o => o[k] >= v.startDate && o[k] <= v.endDate; },
        INCLUDES(k, v) { return o => v.includes(o[k]); },
        GLOBAL(k, v) { v = v.toLowerCase(); return o => Object.values(o).some(s => s.toString().toLowerCase().includes(v)); }
    },
    filters = input.map(({ Field, Operation, Values }) => operators[Operation](Field, Values)),
    result = data.filter(o => filters.every(f => f(o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```